# Trigger Error in salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, null-pointer

When I used to create the record in Event object it is showing error like:

> Error: Invalid Data.
>   Apex trigger General_Event_Trigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: General_Event_Trigger: execution of BeforeINsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.EventClass.updateNewCustomFieldsEvent: line 369, column 1

Trigger code:

```
trigger General_Event_Trigger on Event (...)
{
    if (trigger.isBefore)
    {
        if (trigger.isInsert)
        {
            EventClass.updateNewCustomFieldsEvent(trigger.new);
        }
        else if (trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            EventClass.updateNewCustomFieldsEvent(trigger.new);
        }
    }
}
```

Apex class:

```
public static void updateNewCustomFieldsEvent(List<Event> eventList)
{
    for (Event eve : eventList)
    {
        if (Administrators__c.getInstance().Update_field_Last_Modified_End_User__c)
        {
            String userIdString = eve.LastModifiedById;
            eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c = userIdString.subString(0, 15);
            eve.Last_Modified_Date_End_User__c = eve.LastModifiedDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the future, please include all error messages and code as *text*. It is significantly more accessible for the community than images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just checked lastmodified by id is null on a before insert event and this makes sense.

For example (hastily written trigger based approach, not best practice!):

```
trigger eventTrigger on Event (before insert) {
    system.debug(logginglevel.WARN, '^^^ event last modified: '+trigger.new[0].LastModifiedById);
    system.debug(logginglevel.WARN, '^^^ userinfo:  '+userinfo.getUserId());
}
```

returns:

> 11:38:56:001 USER_DEBUG [2]|WARN|^^^ event last modified: null
>
> 11:38:56:001 USER_DEBUG [3]|WARN|^^^ userinfo:  00510000001QaKjAAK

While the null check approach is valid you would end up with blank data, alternatively using the [userinfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_userinfo.htm) class would give you the current user and therefore the user creating the record.

Comment: line No : 369 as  eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c = userIdString.subString(0, 15); eve.LastModifiedDate is not created in before insert,then why it is showing error in 369,it should have to show error in 370 only @Girbot

Comment: Because you are trying to use substring on null.

Comment: what i have to do to rectify the error? substring on Null means, I am not able to understand ,can you please tell for small scenario for my understand

Answer (score 3):

You should check if variable is not null or empty

```
eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c = String.isBlank( userIdString ) ? '' : userIdString.substring(0, 15)
```

However, like other users reasonably suggest, on before trigger userIdString might be always empty.

Comment: line No : 369 as  eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c = userIdString.subString(0, 15); eve.LastModifiedDate is not created in before insert,then why it is showing error in 369,it should have to show error in 370 only @Patlaus