# Null Pointer Exception in salesforce

Tags: before-trigger

When I used to create the record in Event object it is showing error like:

> Error: Invalid Data.
>   Apex trigger General_Event_Trigger caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: General_Event_Trigger: execution of BeforeINsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Class.EventClass.updateNewCustomFieldsEvent: line 369, column 1

Trigger code:

```
trigger General_Event_Trigger on Event (...)
    {
        if (trigger.isBefore)
        {
            if (trigger.isInsert)
            {
                EventClass.updateNewCustomFieldsEvent(trigger.new);
            }
            else if (trigger.isUpdate)
            {
                EventClass.updateNewCustomFieldsEvent(trigger.new);
            }
        }
    }
```

Apex class:

```
public static void updateNewCustomFieldsEvent(List<Event> eventList)
    {
        for (Event eve : eventList)
        {
            if (Administrators__c.getInstance().Update_field_Last_Modified_End_User__c)
            {
                String userIdString = eve.LastModifiedById;
```

**`eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c=userIdString.subString(0,15);`**

**why this line showing Null pointer exception error,In before insert, LastModifiedById will be null,Then Null value should assign to eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c,Then why it is showing error,what is wrong with this line userIdString.subString(0,15)**

```
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is this question any different than your last? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/159993/trigger-error-in-salesforce

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LastModifiedById` would be null in a before insert trigger. You would need to null check `userIdString` variable.

Change:

```
eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c=userIdString.subString(0,15);
```

to:

```
eve.Last_Modified_By_End_User__c = 
    String.isNotEmpty(userIdString) ? 
        userIdString.subString(0,15) :
        '';
```

Always do a null check when you perform a **dot** operation on any variable.

Comment: You might as well just not perform the assignment if it's empty. :)

Comment: Ah you are right, as usual :)